# How to turn a LED if ultranonic HC-SR04 reading is on defined range for some interval

Tags: arduino-uno, led, hc-sr04

My objective is if ultrasonic readings ranging between 1 to 10 cm and no distance change for 10 seconds or more, a LED will turn on. Here is my current code.

```
#define trigPin 7
#define echoPin 8
#define led 13
#define led2 12

long duration, distance, interval = 4000;
int detection = 0;

void setup() {
   Serial.begin (9600);
   pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
   pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
   detection = millis();
}

void loop() {

   ultraSonic();

   if (distance > 0 && distance < 10 && (millis() - detection >= interval)) {
   digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
   digitalWrite(led2, LOW);
   } else {
   digitalWrite(led, LOW);
   digitalWrite(led2, HIGH);
   }

   Serial.print(millis());
   Serial.print(" - ");
   Serial.println(distance);

   delay(250);
}

void ultraSonic() {
   digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
   delayMicroseconds(60);
   digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
   delayMicroseconds(60);
   digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
   duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
   distance = (duration / 2) / 29.1;
}
```

Sorry for my bad english.
Cheers.

Comment: In your primary if statement:
if (distance > 0 && distance < 10 && millis() - detection >= interval)

Consider grouping clauses with parentheses to make order-of-operations explicit. If nothing else, it will improve readability of the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on previous answer and your comment, maybe you can try this one
I assume if the range is ranging 1-10 cm for 10 secs or more the led will turn on:

```
void setup() {
   Serial.begin (9600);
   pinMode(trigPin, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(echoPin, INPUT);
   pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
   pinMode(led2, OUTPUT);
}
int togle = 0;

void loop() {

   ultraSonic();

   if ((distance >= 1) && (distance =< 10)) //dont use (distance>0) 
   //there are possibility you get 0.xx distance
   {
     Serial.print("Distance on range - ");
     if (toggle == 0) 
       {
        toggle=1; 
        detection=millis();
        Serial.println("last detection outside range");
       } else
     if (toggle == 1) 
     {
        Serial.print("last detection in range - ");
        if ((millis()-detection) >= interval)
            {
             Serial.println("objective complete");
            }
        else Serial.println("not enough interval");
     }
   } else
   {
     //turn off the led
     Serial.println("Distance out of range");
     toggle = 0;
   }

}

void ultraSonic() {
   digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
   delayMicroseconds(60);
   digitalWrite(trigPin, HIGH);
   delayMicroseconds(60);
   digitalWrite(trigPin, LOW);
   duration = pulseIn(echoPin, HIGH);
   distance = (duration / 2) / 29.1;
}
```

Feel free to tell if something is not right

Comment: Sir, thanks for your help. Can you explain about starttime that you made it in the code?

Comment: ah sorry I did not notice that. I fixed the answers

Comment: the result of that code is the led turned on after distance is more than 10 cm. any suggestion sir?

Comment: Can you provide more information? About the test condition, results, expected results, etc

Comment: the result I expect is if the distance is between 1 and 10 cm, and no change in distance in a minimum of 10 seconds, the led turn on. as long as the distance still no changed after 10 seconds, the led still on. but if any change in distance after that, the led will turn off.

Comment: its debugging time then. I update my answer, tell me what you got

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/48263/discussion-between-dpw-and-ian).

Comment: great. everything is working as my expected result. thanks for everyone.

Answer (score 1):

```
void loop() {

   ultraSonic();

   if ((distance > 0) && (distance =< 10)) {
   digitalWrite(led, HIGH);
   digitalWrite(led2, LOW); // turning LED on
   } else {
   digitalWrite(led, LOW);
   digitalWrite(led2, HIGH); // turning LED off
   }

   Serial.print(millis());
   Serial.print(" - ");
   Serial.println(distance);

   delay(250);
}
```

Comment: sir, how about the timing? what i want is if no change in distance for more than 10 seconds then led will turn on. Cheers.

Comment: Take an integer and increase it every time that the object is on the required distance. If it's not, you set it back to 0. You can then check if the integer is as high as required (amount of checks done). Find a neat way to put a little delay between the checks, and you're set.

Comment: Paul is correct, but using integer as counter will less precise. Even if delay is arranged neatly, a small change in program can decrease the accuracy of "10 secs". But its simple and great if the "10 secs" accuracy is not too important